# Regex for replacing unicodes after <ed>

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace this pattern:

```
Hi u+1f33a <ed><u+00a0><u+00bd><ed><u+00b9><u+0084><ed><u+00a0><u+00be><ed><u+00b4>
```

with blank space in Python. I am using following regex:

```
line = re.sub(r'(?:<ed><u\+[0-9a-f]+)>+', r'', line)
```

This regex is not doing anything.

I want output as:

```
Hi u+1f33a
```

I want to retain emoji Unicode in the output.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of the text you're wanting to use this on, the current output, and the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = "Hi u+1f33a <ed><u+00a0><u+00bd><ed><u+00b9><u+0084><ed><u+00a0><u+00be><ed><u+00b4>"
line = re.sub(r'<ed>.*', "", s)
```

`'<ed>.*` matches pattern `<ed>` followed by 0 or more characters

For your second question in the comment:

```
s = 'Fast charging is lit <ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B1><U+008C> 1:37'
re.sub(r'<ed>.*>', "", s)
```

Output:  `Fast charging is lit  1:37`

Comment: Thanks. In the example such as 'Fast charging is lit <ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B1><U+008C> 1:37'. I want output as: Fast charging is lit 1:37

Comment: Added to the answer

Comment: Second, regex worked for me. Thanks. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
import re
line = "Hi u+1f33a <ed><u+00a0><u+00bd><ed><u+00b9><u+0084><ed><u+00a0><u+00be><ed><u+00b4>"
print (re.sub(r'<ed>(?:<u\+[0-9A-Fa-f]+>)+', '', line))
```

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/RHVU71018) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o5sNPA/1).

**Note**: if there can be no `<u+XXXX>` after `<ed>`, replace the last `+` with `*` (to match zero or more occurrences instead of one or more).

**Details**

- `<ed>` - matches `<ed>`
- `(?:<u\+[0-9A-Fa-f]+>)+` - 1 or more repetitions of

  - `<u\+` - `<u+` substring
  - `[0-9A-Fa-f]+` - 1+ hex chars
  - `>` -  a `>` char.